# Detect avalability of page in printer connected to serial port in c#

Tags: c#, printing, serial-port

I have a printer connected to COM1 port of my PC, I am easily able to get print out of it through simple lines of code

```
        SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        myPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        if (myPort.IsOpen == false) //if not open, open the port
            myPort.Open();                 
            myPort.WriteLine("Hello World");          

        myPort.Close();
```

But befor printing I want to make sure that my printer has pages available, can any one tell me how can I do that, or any reference I can get?

I thought of reading the port by modifying the above code like this

```
        SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        myPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        if (myPort.IsOpen == false) //if not open, open the port
            myPort.Open();
            myPort.WriteLine("Hello World");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        label3.Text = myPort.ReadLine();    
        myPort.Close();
```

But when I run my modified code, it freezes whole application. I am new this stuff so soyyr if am stupid anywhere.
Suggest something ...........

Comment: A printer never uses Handshake.None.  If they talk back through the COM port at all then you'll first have to send it a specific command.  Look in the printer's programming manual.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine() freezes untill a line is received. Please refer to  the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e79eaa7-0981-4afa-ae35-0f68f02bc952/frozen-serial-port)

You can set ReadTimeout for SerialPort like as below:

```
SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

myPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
if (myPort.IsOpen == false) //if not open, open the port
myPort.Open();
myPort.WriteLine("Hello World");
myPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
label3.Text = myPort.ReadLine();    
myPort.Close();
```